Cannot read variant data in Snowflake from an entire file
I have an issue in that I am trying to create an external table on files that contain string data (with no extension). The issue is, the files are in this format
s3://bucket_name/file1/date1/time1/file1
s3://bucket_name/file1/date2/time2/file2
s3://bucket_name/file1/date3/time3/file3

The data in different files should be in it's own record (variant).
I tried this so far
create or replace external table dev_analytics_db.dbt_spachari.test (
    file_content variant as (value:c1::variant)
)
with location = @EXT_STG_S3_GROUP_ARCHIVING/ZL 
file_format = (TYPE = CSV SKIP_HEADER = 1)
pattern = '.*.*'
;

But the issue is, each row (in each file) is in it's own row. I want the entire file data in 1 row.

Try creating your own file format and set the field and record delimiters to values that will never appear in your files
